# opening everything for forward only zone centos

Tags: linux, centos, bind, dns-zone

We have a forward only server, which has forward lookup zones and no self-awareness (to resolve any name other than the zone file records). This setup was created for the clients to restrict the access on any sites other than what we want them to visit to (mentioned in zone records) *such as www.example.com*

Problem with this Type of setup is that if, for example, www.example.com has additional links configured i.e. www.pluginx.com, www.pluginapi.com/js etc. then the names will not be resolved and hence the things will not work as expected.

Is here any other way we can forward the query to our/google public dns by choosing only sites we want the clients to visit and without lookup failure ? We are using bind9.

**current setup**

```
zone "fonts.googleapis.com" {
        type forward;
        forwarders { 8.8.8.8; };
        forward only;
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks